# Laravel queue lead to DB connections count overflow?

Tags: database, laravel, multithreading, postgresql, queue

I am using t2.medium (2 cores, 4GB RAM) AWS PostgreSQL RDS as database with Laravel as backend. The queue driver is database. I have just only 2k daily users.

Yesterday, the system was down because of full connections count to DB without prediction. After investigating, I find out that the cause is queues. They 're spawned too much as database can consume.

Here is my supervisord config:

```
[program:mydata-worker]
command=php xxxxxx/artisan queue:work database --tries=5 --timeout=300
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=15
```

This query counts in **1h** , 66k queues are waiting here, but just 3k are consumed:

[image: connsction overflows]

This is in good condition, all queue are consumed
[image: normal_condition]

The question here are :

1. Does my supervisord.conf correct? Should I reduce '--tries=5' or 'numprocs' ?
2. Is it safe if I drop 'jobs' table when the connections count reach the threshhold (100 for example) ?
3. Can you guy give me a hint to design multi-thread safe servers?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, because of 'FOR UPADTE' it locked the workers. I explained in this post => https://medium.com/@taitran.apps/how-to-fix-queue-deadlock-in-laravel-using-postgres-74c1523203b6